# VTP updates through router!

Tags: switching, vtp

Can vtp client revisions be updated from another server switch that connect it only through a router? 
 the two switches are in the same domain name

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

VTP is a layer 2 protocol and therefore can't be forwarded over a layer 3 boundary.  Also, since Vlans terminate at a layer 3 boundary, why would you want to?